# Excel Pivot Table - How to get ALL data to display when using "SHOW DETAIL"

Tags: pivot-table, excel-2010

When in Pivot table, I have 80K distinct data rows. How do I display and return all data when I select cell and do the SHOW DETAIL function?
When I do, I just get 1000 rows of data in a separate worksheet and not the 80K. I get this output 'Data returned for Distinct Count of Name (First 1000 rows)."
How do I display ALL rows?

Any assistance is much appreciated. Thank you. WD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Data -> "Queries & Connections" (1).
Then click on the connections (2) and go to "ThisWorkbookDataModel". Right click and choose "Properties..." (3).

[image]

Change the number of maximum rows to retrieve in the "Connection Properties" window:

*(The larger the dataset, the longer and heavier the excel workbook will be, when you retrieve the data)*

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I was losing sleep over this. :)  Thank you Thank you and Thank you. WD

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to accept the answer ([grey tick mark below voting buttons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow)). Good luck with your project :)